# write web serice for android with C#

Tags: web-services, android-service

i want write a web service with C# to call from an android app

in my web service i wrote  HElloWorld()  method to calles and ConvertDataTableTojSonString to converted data to Json  i downloaded  converting fonction from internet  , my probleim is ConvertDataTableTojSonString function it's return me some thing like

```
"[{\"ProId\":1,\"ProcName\":\"لبنیات\"},{\"ProId\":2,\"ProcName\":\"لوازم بهداشتی\"},{\"ProId\":3,\"ProcName\":\"لوازم آرایشی\"},{\"ProId\":4,\"ProcName\":\"خشکبار\"},{\"ProId\":5,\"ProcName\":\"نوشیدنی ها\"},{\"ProId\":6,\"ProcName\":\"سبزیجات\"},{\"ProId\":7,\"ProcName\":\"فرآورده های گوشتی\"}]"
```

the json format that return is not recognizable for my android app i dont need that '/'  befor and after items . 
any body can help me to find an fanction to change my data table to JSON format for use in android app , thank you : )

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void HelloWorld() {
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    HelloWorldData data = new HelloWorldData();
    data.Message = ConvertDataTableTojSonString(db.Select("select * from ProCategory ",CommandType.Text));
    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(data.Message));
}

public String ConvertDataTableTojSonString(DataTable dataTable)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer =
           new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

    List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRows = new List<Dictionary<String, Object>>();

    Dictionary<String, Object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        tableRows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(tableRows);
}
```